# User input to Array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to take user input and add it to an array of strings. I only want to add one element to the array. However the program stops running straight after it prints "enter new task" So I've no time to enter in a task. And it says build successful. What am I doing wrong??

**My code:**

```
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
 String[] taskList= new String[100];

 System.out.println("Enter new task");
 taskList[0] = reader.nextLine();
```

**Output:**

```
Enter new task

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: seems like u only build your project but didn't run it

Comment: It may be IDE problem. which one are you using? Try to run it from command line.

Comment: could you put the complete code? Is this block inside a loop?

Comment: the program work fine i can type the String

Comment: Which IDE are you using. You are not using one of those online IDEs, are you?

Comment: This code works. may be you need to clean and build the project from your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Scanner read one extra line every time

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] taskList= new String[100];

System.out.println("Enter new task");
reader.nextLine();
taskList[0] = reader.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try yhis code:

```
String[] tasks = new String[1];
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter new task: ");
String task = reader.readLine();
tasks[0] = task;
System.out.println("Your task is: " + task);
```

Hope it helps.